# Can I use two DividendDistributor in Reflection token for two tokens

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity

I'm going to create reflection tokens for two tokens

Token Name Friend Token

Token Symbol FT

For example Token A, Token B

10% buy/sell tax

- 2.5% goes to A reflections for holders
- 2.5% goes to B reflections for holders
- 3% buys FT & burns
- 2% FT LP

But I'm finding way to reflection two tokens and just look DividendDistributor and I think I can use that for two tokens reflections.

And Also going to burn 1% of total supply everyday for 88 days automatically

Does it can be done via smart contract?

Is this possible to do that?

For burn 1% of total supply, I'm going to use node.js for call burn function everyday